# ng change event not firing on checkbox if it's set by javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created one directive for checkbox which makes an image layer,
but problem is that it's not firing ng change event if even input box checked value is changed

Directive

```
function icheck($timeout,$parse) {
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, $attrs, $watch) {
            var value = $attrs['value'],
                ngModelGetter = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);

            return $timeout(function () {

                $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
                    $(element).iCheck('update');
                });

                $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
                }).on('ifChanged', function (event) {

                    var elemType = $(element).attr('type');

                    if (elemType === 'checkbox' && $attrs.ngModel) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            console.log(event.target.checked)
                            return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, event.target.checked);

                        });
                    }
                    else if (elemType === 'radio' && $attrs.ngModel) {
                        return $scope.$apply(function () {
                            return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, value);
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    };
}
```

HTML BELOW

```
<input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" data-icheck ng-change="alert('changed!')" ng-model="chekal" id="chkSelectAll">
```

Any idea how I can trigger ng change event on even click event will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did was passing funciton value in attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" data-icheck data-function="selectAll" ng-model="chekal" id="chkSelectAll">
```

directive

```
                if (elemType === 'checkbox' && $attrs.ngModel) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        console.log(event.target.checked)
                        var f = $(event.target).data('function');
                        console.log(f);
                        if (f !== "undefined" || f !== "") {
                            eval('$scope.' + f + '(event)');
                        }
                        return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, event.target.checked);

                    });
                }
```

so I called the function with that eval thing. This answer is just for reference so it can help others as well.

I don't wanted to add adhoc of watches so did it without increasing watches and solved question with more performance way.

Comment: If this worked, then you ought to accept it as the answer

Comment: Np. It is always ok to accept your own answer if there is no other, better answer. That way, people reading the question in future know what the solution is (you probably forgot because you can't accept your own answer until two days after you post the question).

Answer (score 3):

Documentation of ngChange:

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input

If you want to watch the model, use `$scope.watch`

```
$scope.$watch('chekal', function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
          if (newvalue !== oldvalue){
              //write code here
          }});
```

Comment: solved 90% but now issue is that when I refresh page then that function executes first like I alerted some thing now it's firing first on page load

Comment: @cverb This shouldn't be necessary, since ng-change should fire if used correctly.

Comment: @thwiegan As he is saying in his title, the event doesn't fire when it's set via javascript, which is just normal behaviour (see the Angular documentation).

@nirmal Put `if (newvalue !== oldvalue)` check in your watch function.

Comment: @thwiegan ng change event is not firing don't know reason may be as I am changing through directive. But now thing is that it triggers event on page load first time

Comment: @livepo it worked but I have used mine solution, that's why I have not accepted the answer not even mine but upvote for sure thanks cverb

Answer (score 0):

Change your `icheck` function to `directive` as below:

```
yourapp.directive('icheck', function($timeout,$parse) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, $attrs, $watch) {
                var value = $attrs['value'],
                    ngModelGetter = $parse($attrs['ngModel']);

                return $timeout(function () {

                    $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
                        $(element).iCheck('update');
                    });

                    $(element).iCheck({
                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
                    }).on('ifChanged', function (event) {

                        var elemType = $(element).attr('type');

                        if (elemType === 'checkbox' && $attrs.ngModel) {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                console.log(event.target.checked)
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, event.target.checked);

                            });
                        }
                        else if (elemType === 'radio' && $attrs.ngModel) {
                            return $scope.$apply(function () {
                                return ngModelGetter.assign($scope, value);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And add `data-i-check` as an attribute to input tag instead of `data-icheck`.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" data-i-check ng-change="alert('changed!')" ng-model="chekal" id="chkSelectAll">
```

Comment: it's already directive, please read the question and still not triggering change event

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('chekal', function(newvalue,oldvalue) {
  if (newvalue && newvalue !== oldvalue){
      // here you go
  }
});
```